# How to prioritise multiple => constraints so that they come into effect in a certain order

Tags: ios, swift, autolayout, interface-builder, nslayoutconstraint

So, I am trying to make a view like this that is scalable on all the iPhone devices from `iPhone X` to `iPhone SE`.

The three constraints are marked on the screen named 1, 2, and 3. All three of these constraints have `Greater than equal to` attribute set to have a minimum buffer of `5 points` from the margins.

Now, I would like to see this view on `iPhone SE`, the `iPhone 8` family, and the `plus` family but I would like to specify that:

1. constraint 1 should decrease in size first,
2. constraints 2 should decrease in size second, and
3. constraint 3 should decrease in size third

[image]

I tried multiple configurations with the priorities, and even though my intuition tells me that there might be a solution in the `content hugging` and `compression resistance` values, these are not available for the constraints themselves.

How can I accomplish this on the interface builder?

Comment: Your description is ambiguous. Suppose there are 60 available to be distributed across these three gaps. Each can be 5 points with 45 points left over. Where do you want to put the 45 points? You could do 5/5/50, or 20/20/20, or 10/20/30, or many other combinations.

Answer (score 2):

It is possible, but you need two constraints per flexible distance you want. Try set it up as follows:

1a. Vertical space constraint >= min, priority 1000
 1b. Vertical space constraint = max, priority 900
 2a. Vertical space constraint >= min, priority 1000
 2b. Vertical space constraint = max, priority 910
 3a. Vertical space constraint >= min, priority 1000
 3b. Vertical space constraint = max, priority 920

Where `min` is the minimum distance you want, and `max` is the maximum distance. 1a and 1b corresponds to your constraint 1 and so on.

Note two things, if you view becomes smaller than is allowed with all priorities on `min` you will get layout errors. If the view is larger than all `max`values, the *first* distance (lowest priority) will extend.